# How to amend a xml element text in PowerShell script

Tags: xml, powershell

I need to amend multiple paths in a xml file. I need to read in all the paths and then add my system information to each one. How do I read in all the paths, store them in a variable then update them. `$path= $newText + oldPath`

```
<monitor> 
   <fileProcessor>
    <pathConfiguration>
      <path>/path/to/file</path>
</pathConfiguration>
</fileProcessor>
</monitor>
```

```powershell
$newText= "C:/users/name"

foreach ($element in $xmlDoc.monitor.fileProcessor.pathConfiguration.path)
{
  $element = $newText + existingText
}
```

Comment: PLEASE add enuf code to be workable. for instance, you have not included how you got the XML string into a PoSh object. lookee ... How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - Help Center - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also, use cmdlet `Join-Path` when combining paths elements together instead of `+` to make sure the parts are combined correctly (not forgetting a backslash or doubling this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the InnerText property. Something like below might work:

```powershell
$XML =
[XML]@"
<monitor> 
   <fileProcessor>
    <pathConfiguration>
      <path>/path/to/file</path>
</pathConfiguration>
</fileProcessor>
</monitor>
"@

$newText = "C:/users/name/"

ForEach($Path in $XML.monitor.fileProcessor.pathConfiguration.ChildNodes )
{
    $Path.InnerText = $newText + $Path
}
```

You could certainly use a `ForEach-Object` as well. Here's an example using a variable assignment as you mentioned in your question:

```powershell
$XML =
[XML]@"
<monitor> 
   <fileProcessor>
    <pathConfiguration>
      <path>/path/to/file</path>
</pathConfiguration>
</fileProcessor>
</monitor>
"@

$newText = "C:/users/name/"

$ChildPathNodes = $XML.monitor.fileProcessor.pathConfiguration.ChildNodes

$ChildPathNodes |
ForEach-Object{
    $_.InnerText = $newText + $_.InnerText
}
```

You can check the result with: `$XML.monitor.fileProcessor.pathConfiguration`