# How to Generate Random Password & update in XML

Tags: xml, powershell, automation

I have the below script which generates a random password and I want to use the generated random password auto updated into my xml whenever I execute that powershell script.

**PowerShell script--**

```
$Password = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$Password | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name "Password" -Value { ("!@#$%^&*0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".tochararray() | sort {Get-Random})[0..16] -join '' }
```

**XML file content --**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BAPI xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="BAPI.xsd">
    <OPs Resource="https://XYZSevr:11231/api/Ops">
        <Password>ashdjaks723</Password>
    </OPs>
</BAPI>
```

Comment: Can you put a more realistic representation of the XML you are dealing with? I'm tempted to say you just need to get down to the element and set the innerText property. Similar to [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66190583/4749264)

Comment: Thanks Steven, its just to avoid confusion I just updated the line which I want to expose, however as per your suggestions, I have updated my xml if you can suggest something now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this ought to do it:

```
$xmlFile = "D:\Test\YourXmlFile.xml"   # put your file here
$xml = New-Object System.XML.XMLDocument
$xml.Load($xmlFile)

$pwChars = "!@#$%^&*0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray()
$password = ($pwChars | Sort-Object {Get-Random})[0..16] -join ''

# set the password on the Password element inside the OPs element where it matches the Resource attribute
($xml.BAPI.OPs | Where-Object {$_.Resource -eq "https://XYZSevr:11231/api/Ops"}).Password = $password

# save the updated xml
$xml.Save($xmlFile)
```

---

A quick word about the XML special characters, in this case the `&`

In XML, there are five special characters that are not allowed in an elements value. These are `<`, `&`, `>`, the double-quote `"` and the single-quote `'`.

The code above to save a password containing such a character automatically 'entifies' these characters into resp. `&lt;`, `&amp;`, `&gt;`, `&quot;` and `&apos;`.
In some cases numeric entities are used instead (like `&` becomes `&#38;`).

When you open the XML in a text editor, you might think these entities ruin the password and if the next script or application tries to parse the XML using **textual** means like regex, then it indeed could return the saved password including the `&amp;`.
If the script using the XML however plays by the XML rules on this, there is nothing to fear, because the entities are converted back to the characters they represent automatically aswell.

Let's assume your saved XML looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BAPI xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="BAPI.xsd">
  <OPs Resource="https://XYZSevr:11231/api/Ops">
    <Password>MP_jFmu0&amp;sXBgEWcw</Password>
  </OPs>
</BAPI>
```

As you can see, the `&` character is written there as `&amp;`

Using Powershell, just read the saved password back like this:

```
$xmlFile = "D:\Test\YourXmlFile.xml"   # put your file here
$xml = New-Object System.XML.XMLDocument
$xml.Load($xmlFile)

$password = ($xml.BAPI.OPs | Where-Object {$_.Resource -eq "https://XYZSevr:11231/api/Ops"}).Password

$password
```

The resulting value in `$password` is 'de-entified' into `MP_jFmu0&sXBgEWcw`, just like you intended.

Comment: many thanks Theo, its working as expected but password is getting invalid things like below- <Password>w#YeKaRscWnXC&amp;VH1</Password>   &amp; is not right

Comment: Got it special character "&" is creating problem while generating password hence when I removed it, its working fine:-)

Comment: @Theo great additions. Very helpful stuff on the characters.  May I ask why you're Sorting? Is that to further decrease predictability?

Comment: @Steven Thanks. The sorting is to hussle the characters to use in random order, which indeed makes the result less predictable.

Comment: @Theo et al. Since parsing XML text w/ RegEx was mentioned, check out [this blog post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) from 1 of the founders of SO, RE: Parsing HTML with RegEx.  I wouldn't rule it out, it would depend on the task, nevertheless, the article is somewhat funny.

Answer (score 2):

To augment [@Theos great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66506767/4749264), I was just exploring alternative patterns and/or syntax.  Don't accept this answer, I just figured since I worked it out differently I might as well share it.

```
$XmlFile  = "C:\temp\yourXmlFile.xml"
$PwdChars = [Char[]](65..90 + 97..122 + 48..57) + [Char[]]"!@#$%^*_"
$Pass     = (Get-Random -InputObject $PwdChars -Count 16) -join ''
$XPath    = "/BAPI/OPs[@Resource='https://XYZSevr:11231/api/Ops']"

$Xml = [XML]::new()
$Xml.Load( $XmlFile )   
    
# Use Select-Xml cmdlet to change the password:
(Select-Xml -Xml $Xml -XPath $XPath).Node.PassWord = $Pass

# Save the updated XML:
$Xml.Save( $XmlFile )
```

Above I'm using the range operator to compile a list of acceptable characters instead of typing them out. There's no real benefit other than a slightly shorter or more nuanced syntax.

The other difference is using an xPath query with `Select-Xml`.

Optionally you can skip `Select-Xml` by using the `.SelectSingleNode(...)` method:

```
$Xml.SelectSingleNode($XPath).Password = $Pass
```

You can also set the password directly with `$xml.BAPI.OPs.Password = $Pass`. In the Above examples I left it conditional except implemented via the xPath query instead of a `Where{}` clause.  This approach is not case sensitive, while both xPath approaches are.  This is because in the first case "." referencing is a PowerShell characteristic, while the xPath is specific to XML which is itself case sensitive.  Using `Where{}` clause in conjunction with this would remain case insensitive, again because `Where{}` is PowerShell not XML.